# Compare array1 with the arrays of a multidimensional array (Array2 & array3)

Tags: php, arrays

I want to compare the values of **sandra_array** with **john_array** and then  with **sem_array**.

I can compare **sandra_array** with **john_array** with:

```
<?php
$sandra_array = array("soccer" => "10", "basketball" => "20", "atletics" => "40");

$john_array = array("soccer" => "15", "basketball" => "15", "atletics" => "45");
$sem_array = array("soccer" => "5", "basketball" => "10", "atletics" => "50");

$common_sports = array_keys(array_intersect_key($sandra_array, $john_array));
$points_sandra_array = $points_john_array = array_fill_keys($common_sports, 0);

foreach ($common_sports as $common_sport) {
if ($sandra_array[$common_sport] > $john_array[$common_sport]) {
    $points_sandra_array[$common_sport]++;
} else if ($sandra_array[$common_sport] < $john_array[$common_sport]) {
    $points_john_array[$common_sport]++;
}
}

foreach ($common_sports as $common_sport) {

}

echo "Sandra (", array_sum($points_sandra_array).") vs John (", array_sum($points_john_array).")";
?>
```

Result

```
Sandra (1) vs John (2)
```

I want to have also the results of Sandra against Sem. Like this:

```
Sandra (1) vs John (2)
Sandra (2) vs Sem(1)
```

I was thinking about making the following multidimensional array:

```
$array_other_players = array($john_array,$sem_array);
```

and then with foreach I will compare first the points of Sandra with the points of John and then with the points of Sem. But I don't know how to do it.

Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

- First declare an array containing opponents players' array, like this:

  ```
  $players_array = array('John' => $john_array, 'Sem' => $sem_array);
  ```
- And then loop through each opponent player to calculate the final score.

So your code should be like this:

```
$sandra_array = array("soccer" => "10", "basketball" => "20", "atletics" => "40");
$john_array = array("soccer" => "15", "basketball" => "15", "atletics" => "45");
$sem_array = array("soccer" => "5", "basketball" => "10", "atletics" => "50");

// Declare an array containing opponents players' array
$players_array = array('John' => $john_array, 'Sem' => $sem_array);

// Loop through each opponent player to calculate the final score
foreach($players_array as $opponent_player => $opponent_player_array){
    $common_sports = array_keys(array_intersect_key($sandra_array, $opponent_player_array));
    $points_sandra_array = $points_opponent_array = array_fill_keys($common_sports, 0);

    foreach ($common_sports as $common_sport) {
        if ($sandra_array[$common_sport] > $opponent_player_array[$common_sport]) {
            $points_sandra_array[$common_sport]++;
        } else if ($sandra_array[$common_sport] < $opponent_player_array[$common_sport]) {
            $points_opponent_array[$common_sport]++;
        }
    }

    echo "Sandra (". array_sum($points_sandra_array).") vs {$opponent_player} (". array_sum($points_opponent_array) .")<br />";
}
```

Output:

```
Sandra (1) vs John (2)
Sandra (2) vs Sem (1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Rajdeep Paul:)